# Notations and justification for $P(F_\theta(Y) > \alpha) \geq 1- \alpha$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In my script there is the following assumptions:

$Y$ is a random variable with values in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $F_\theta$ is a distribution function with: 
$$ P(Y \leq c) = F_\theta (c)$$
Then it says that one can easily show that:

$$P(F_\theta(Y) > \alpha) \geq 1 - \alpha$$ and
$$P(F_\theta(Y - 1) > 1 - \alpha) \geq 1 - \alpha$$
with $\alpha \in [0,1]$.

My question are: what is $F_\theta(Y)$? Do I have to replace the $c$ with another r.v.?

How do I start to verify this assumption?

Answer (score 0):

$F_{\theta}(Y)$ is a transformation of random variable, and as such it is random variable by itself.

As for the assumption, you could follow this:
\begin{equation}
P(F_{\theta}(Y)>\alpha)=1-P(F_{\theta}(Y)\leq\alpha)= \\=1-P(Y\leq\arg\max_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}\{F_{\theta}(z)\leq\alpha\}) \\ = 1-F_{\theta}(\arg\max_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}\{F_{\theta}(z)\leq\alpha\})\geq 1-\alpha
\end{equation}

The proof for the second assumption is similar.